# Implement part of code to be executed on my specified device(s)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uniqueidentifier

I want a piece of code only executed on my specific test devices even after sent for production. I don't want this code to run for everyone who downloads my app.

I was thinking of using UDID, however Apple forbids this. I was looking for some solution to get unique device ID, but it seems there is no such a thing nowadays. Any suggestions on how can I uniquely identify only my own selected devices?

Comment: Why don't you use a TestFlight build to test this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A popular mechanism for this is by [Defining a Custom URL Scheme for Your App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app).

For example, your handler could do something like this:

```swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 open url: URL,
                 options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:] ) -> Bool {
   guard url.scheme == "myphotoapp" else { return false }

   if url.path == "/polling" {
      // switch to polling
   } else if url.path == "/events" {
      // switch to polling
   }

   return true
}
```

You can then call your new `myphotoapp:` scheme from Safari or Mail to activate your test functionality.

Comment: I think this is the most elegant solution. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could store a long string in a file on the device. When the app starts it checks for this file and checks for this string. if this file and string match it knows it is one of the 2 devices that you designated.

In reality you should probably be able to just write an update to the app and program it onto your own devices straight from xcode and bypass the app store altogether for testing purposes.

Comment: Can you explain the second part a little bit? I don't get it. I think this is what I do right now - run it from xcode on my device and/or via publishing a build via Crashlytics Beta. Unfortunately none of these approaches produces a build working with production Game Center but with test, which I found unreliable. That's why I came up with the idea to uniquely identify my devices after the app is downloaded from the App Store and then only on my devices to be able to switch the underlying mechanism.

Comment: It probably is what you do already thanks for the clarification. Would doing a test flight of your app give you access to the production game center? I think you can choose who to invite.